# Why xpath text() node cannot be nested in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I encounter a problem when playing around xpath selector.

```
response.xpath('//*[text()="Revenue"]/text()/.')


response.xpath('//*[text()="Revenue"]/text()').xpath('.')
```

I was expecting two codes above output the same thing. The first one works fine,but the second one returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, there is a feature request to get selectors of text to behave as any other selectors ([parsel #130](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/130)).